# C++ proper usage, this pointer

Tags: c++, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I make explicit use of the `this` pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer)

I'm wondering about the proper usage of the "this" pointer.

I've seen someone create a class constructor with the argument passed variable passed in named 'data'.
However he had a private member variable named 'data' already thus he simply used:

`this->data = data;`

would have worked to simply use

`data = data_in`

(if the parameter was named data_in), and no need to invoke the "this" pointer and reference the member type.

Now I'm wondering, is this proper usage? Using `this->member` to reduce on naming complexity? I mean it works and I see that it accomplishes what was intended but I'm wondering if some of you more experienced C++ guys and girls can say a word or two if this is common practice?

Also, out of curiosity I've instrumented the code just to see what happens under the hood, and it seems the "this" pointer is invoked anyhow. I guess that's the way references to the class object are done anyways.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Some what name it differently, some would assign in as `: data(data)` (if applicable), some would use `this->data`, others will go for `classname::data`. Whatever pleases your aesthetics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, specifically dereferencing the `this` pointer to access a non-static data-member of the class instance is unnecessary, but it can help with naming confusion, especially when the data-members of the class are defined in a separate header file from the code-module.  However, it *is necessary* to use the `this` pointer if you are accessing a non-static data-member that is a member of a base-class that is a templated class.  In other words, in a situation like:

```
template<typename T>
class base_class
{
    protected:
        int a;
};

template<typename T>
class derived_class : public base_class<T>
{
    void function()
    {
        a = 5; //this won't work
        this->a = 5; //this will work
    }
};
```

you'll note that you must use the `this` pointer in order to properly resolve the inherited non-static data-member from the template base-class.  This is due to the fact that `base_class<T>::a` is a dependent name, in this case dependent on the template parameter `T`, but when used without the `this` pointer, it is treated as a non-dependent name, and is therefore not looked up in the dependent base-class namespace.  Thus without the specific dereference of the `this` pointer, you'll end up with a compiler error like "`a` was not declared in this scope", or something similar.

Comment: Your snippet of code of "a=5" without "this->" compiles on VisualStudio.

Comment: Hmm, not in gcc ... you get the problem I described ...http://ideone.com/H7DDza

Answer (score 2):

No accessing a class member as:

```
this->member = something;
```

is same as accessing the member by itself,

```
member = something;
```

The compiler sees both as same and their is no overhead involved. Even if you use the second format the compiler does the same as first format under the hood.

In short, trying to use either of the two formats with aim of improving performance is useless. Ofcourse, You might have to use the first format in some template cases( accessing non-static data members of a templated Base class) but that is not for performance.

Comment: With the caveat that @Jason pointed out...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ofcourse,It is good to mention that though OP's main aim in asking the Q was performance related IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially identical, except as Jason pointed out.

The nice part is that if you use `this->` most editors will code complete for you, saving you typing.

Answer (score 0):

It is "correct", but it is also poor practice.  Naming parameters the same as class members is a bad idea.  Intentionally creating naming conflicts is a bad idea.

Scoping operators are designed for when naming conflicts are unavoidable, such as when overriding a base member, or when using two libraries with identifier names chosen independently.  Don't consider them free license for doing stupid things.

Unless you're practicing for an obfuscated code contest.  Then by all means introduce naming collisions.