# advantages of this pointer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [When should I make explicit use of the `this` pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer)

In C++, what are the advantages of using the `this` pointer? i.e. **Which of the following two snippets is preferred?**

```
class stud
{
  int a;
  public:
  void run(int a) {
      stud::a=a;
  }
};
```

OR

```
 class stud { 
   int a; 
   public: 
   void run(int a){ 
     this->a=a;
    }
 };
```

Why the 1st case isn't used instead?

Comment: Did you try compiling it?  Are they really any different?

Comment: No... they are the same. Exactly my question! Then why is *this* pointer used? What exactly is it's Purpose?

Comment: @user2038517: For occasions that are not this occasion. You can use `this` for many other things than accessing members. When you need it for those things, you'll know. You should really read the question of which yours has been marked a duplicate.

Comment: @user2038517: Interestingly, you seem to believe as the accepted answer in the linked question, that it does not matter. Well, it **does** matter in a few cases. In particular, the qualification inhibits dynamic dispatch to virtual functions. If `a` was a virtual function in your class, `this->a()` would call the final overrider, while `stud::a()` would call the override in the `stud` level (i.e. never to a more derived type).