# can somebody explain what is "This" operator in C++

Tags: c++

I know that "this" operator is used to access member functions of invoking object,but they can be called normally also .So,what exactly is the use of "this" operator.

Comment: Try reading the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) it explains exactly what `this` is and when it is needed

Comment: He wants to know when this keyword is needed, not what it means.

Comment: Voting to close for not having a basic understanding is not fair.  My interpretation is that the poster is basically asking "when *must* you use the this pointer," and there is an answer to that question.  Moreover, most C++ programmers couldn't answer the question.  That being said, this question has been asked and answered many times before, and is a dupe.  It should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: This has been asked before in SO

Comment: This question is closed for, IMO, the wrong reason.  But it *should* be closed as a dupe, so I'm not going to vote to repoen.  In any case, if you want to know when you *must* use the `this` pointer, here is the dupe I would have linked to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer

Comment: @JohnDibling Not even there, there are alternatives :)

Comment: @jrok:  I'm referring to dependant names, which is buried a bit.

Comment: @JohnDibling Me too. You can write either `this->member` or `someclass<T>::member`.

Comment: @jrok: aha!  actually i think i knew that...

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is such a bad question. He is not asking what this does, but why the keyword exists when this is implied most of the time.

Here is a case where this pointer is necessary

```
class Test
{
    int i;

    void Set(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }
};
```

this is used to select between member variable and function parameter with the same name.

this is also used when you need the address of the object within the class.

```
void f(Test *p);

class Test
{
    int i;

    void pass()
    {
        f(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your second example is better, in the first one you could have qualified the name `Test::i`, as you do with any hiding scenario.

Comment: +1:  Passing `this` as a function parameter is an obvious, everyday use.  So obvious I didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator called `this` in C++ - there is an implicit variable that is present in all non-static member functions. Where `this` is a pointer to the current instance of the class.

`this` is also a keyword in the language (in other words, a reserved word, you can't use `this` as a name of a variable or funciton)

`this` can be used to refer to the object.

E.g.

```
class A
{
   int x;
   void some_func()
   {
      this->x = 42;
   }
 };
```

It is superfluous in the above case, but there are situations where it is useful or required.

Comment: Formally, it's a `keyword`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `this` is not an operator (operators are `+`, `-`, and the like). It is a reserved keyword, and also an *expression*.

`this` is used in member functions to refer to the object into which the function is being called. You are right, it is not needed to refer to member variables or member functions, but it is useful if you want to refer to the whole object.

Comment: there are times when you must use `this`

Comment: @John: Are you referring to dependent names?

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm referring to accessing non-static member functions in a base class template.

Comment: @John: In other words, yes, you're referring to dependent names (which may be functions or data members).  That topic is so advanced compared to this question, and ISTR using `this` is only one of several possible ways to resolve those (so that the word "must" is a bit too strong).

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Yes, in other words yes, but I was trying to give a little more so that other readers could do their own research.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I don't think that you'll help solving the OP doubts talking about dependent names name resolution. I'm trying to keep this  as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is a pointer to the instance of your object

Think about the following scenario where this can be used to see one benefit:

```
int add(int a, int b){
   return a + b;
}
```

But lets say you also have a data member that is also named 'b'.

```
return a + b
```

Returns the sum of your arguments

```
return a + this->b
```

Returns the sum of your argument a and the data member b

Comment: A better solution to the name hiding problem is to select sane names for your members & parameters.

Answer (score -1):

As per MSDN:

> The this **pointer (not operator)** is a pointer accessible only within the nonstatic member functions of a class, struct, or union type. It points to the object for which the member function is called. Static member functions do not have a this pointer.

You could use it when, let's say you want to make an assignments like these:

```
myClass::myClass(int x) {
     myGlobalVar = this;
     this-> x = x;
}
```