# Is There a Benefit or Performance Boost By Using 'this ->' to Reference Members of a Class?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

I was wondering is there was an advantage of any kind by using 'this' to reference class members, rather than not using it, in c++?

for example...

```
class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        void print_test()
            {
                std::cout << this -> m_x   // Using 'this'
                          << endl;

                std::cout << m_x          // Rather than referencing 'm_x' this way
                          << endl;
            }
    private:
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
};
```

Comment: Good question. The best way for this case is to see what assembly code the compiler generates.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no performance difference. To the compiler, the meanings are identical.

Well, almost... the only time you specifically need to say `this` is if you have a variable of the same name in an inner scope that shadows the member variable (which is considered bad form anyway), or funny cases where you have a templated base class and you need to tell the compiler that a name refers to a base class member (this is pretty rare though).

Comment: The template requirement is a bit more generic. Anytime you refer to some symbol which is not available at declaration time you need to refer to it via a templated type (often using `this`). I don't think it is rare as I see it quite often (perhaps not using `this` but at least using a template argument).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's just a convention.

The basic idea is that we usually needs to use `this->` to avoid naming conflicts:

```
class Value
{
public:
    Value(): value(0), valueSet(false) {}

    void setValue(int value) {
        //value = value; ( WRONG : Naming conflict )
        this->value = value; // Use this-> to distinguish between them
        valueSet = true;
    }

private:
    int value;
    bool valueSet;
}
```

Now the statement `valueSet = true;` without `this->` looks ugly. So people prefer to prefix `this->` to make all things look consistent:

```
    void setValue(int value) {
        this->value = value;
        this->valueSet = true; // Isn't this consistent and beautiful?
    }
```

But to my knowledge of C++, this pattern is not widely used. If you'd ever looked at some *Java* source code, prefixing `this.` before member field accesses is very common.

PS: Another possible reason is maybe people just want to emphasize it is a member field, not something else. Since most simple editors are not capable of highlighting such fields, it can improve code readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use it it will be implied. So those two writes are equivalent in the compiled code because the compiler will add the `this`.

The only problem that can occur is an ambiguity on a variable name. But as long as you use the convention of prefix (or postfix) member with `m_` or `_m` you should be safe.

Also you can see [When should I make explicit use of the `this` pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

No.. Otherwise everyone would've written code like this. 
Maybe somebody thought it easy to read. Maybe he was a java developer.