# Transpose method for Matrix Class

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a matrix class and I can't decide which method is best to process a matrix transpose.

At first I did the classical way:

```
Matrix Matrix::Transpose()
{
    Matrix M(m_cols, m_rows);

    for(int i=0; i < m_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < m_cols; ++j)
        {
            M(j,i) = this->m_matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return M;
}
```

But on a second thought I was wondering if this way was better in term of memory management:

```
Matrix& Matrix::Transpose()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Matrix> M(new Matrix(*this));

    m_matrix.resize(m_cols);
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < m_matrix.size(); ++i)
    {
        m_matrix[i].resize(m_rows, 0.0);
    }
    m_rows = M->Get_Cols();
    m_cols = M->Get_Rows();

    for(unsigned long i=0; i < M->Get_Rows(); ++i)
    {
        for(unsigned long j=0; j < M->Get_Cols(); ++j)
        {
            this->m_matrix[j][i] = (*M)(i,j);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Now both methods work, but I'm quite new to the "memory management" side of C++ and I can't really tell which one is better in terms of "good practice"...

Comment: These two are not equivalent, notice how the first version can be made `const` as it does not transform the input matrix. The latter one however can work in-place (without allocating extra memory).

Comment: To begin with, the two functions you show do different things. First first one doesn't modify `this` but the other does. The second one also does a lot of extra work that isn't needed if you want to modify `this`.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737298/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first construction is preferable for several reasons, which I've discussed below. FYI: You may find [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) interesting as well.

### Keep It Simple

The second solution is needlessly complex. You've replaced what's essentially 4 lines of code with 9 lines of code. You've also introduced another for loop and the use of heap memory. The second solution is slower, almost by definition, because you're doing *more work*.

### Use the Stack

When working with temporary data structures, as you've done in the second example, you should prefer stack memory. Introducing additional memory allocation introduces overhead  you don't need.

### Avoid Surprising Behavior + Side-Effects

Your second construction modifies your instance, which for this type of transformation could be surprising.

### Hints

Some additional hints for working with C++.

- Don't specify `this->` [unless necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer) - it is implied
- Mark your methods `const` where possible - see the [Cpp Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-const)
- Make use of private implementation within your own class

Regarding the third point above, the `private` keyword applies at a type level, not the instance. Take a look at the code below. What do you think the output is? Notice that within our own class method, we can refer to the private variables of another instance. The `action` method is marked const - so we know it won't affect our instance, but the parameter is a mutable instance that *we can* modify.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    ~Test() = default;
    int x;
    int y;
    void setZ()
    {
        m_z = x * y;
    }
    void action(Test& other) const
    {
        other.m_z = m_z;
    }
    int z() const { return m_z; }
private:
    int m_z;
};

int main()
{
    Test a;
    Test b;
    a.x = 5;
    a.y = 3;
    a.setZ();
    a.action(b);
    cout << b.z() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```