# Templating a Derived class of a Base class that is already templated

Tags: c++, c++11

I get the compiler error "Use of undeclared identifier '_storage'"

```
#include <iostream>

struct Storage{
    int t;
};

struct DerivedStorage : Storage{
    int s;
};

struct DerivedStorage2 : DerivedStorage{
    int r;
};

template<typename DS = Storage>
class Base{
public:
    DS* _storage = nullptr;
    Base(){
        _storage = new DS();
    }
    void m(){
        _storage->t++;
    }
};

template<typename DS = DerivedStorage>
class Derived : public Base<DS>{
public:
    void m2(){
        _storage->s++; //error here
    }
};

template<typename DS = DerivedStorage2>
class Derived2 : public Derived<DS>{
public:

    void m3(){
        _storage->r++; //error here
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Derived2<DerivedStorage2> t;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        t.m3();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Derived` itself does not have a member variable named `_storage`, use `this->_storage` to access `Base`'s `_storage` instead.

```
void m2(){
  this->_storage->s++;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o7z7EGaEf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer This should be useful to explain why.